# Firefox is not showing the "View Page Info" option in the context menu

Tags: firefox, linux

Previously, the right-click context-menu for Firefox would offer the "View Page Info" option as shown in the below image.

[image]

Recently, not sure when ... that changed and that option is not available for the web pages.

**One weird twist** to this is that **if there is a frame in the page**, and the menu offers the view frame info, I can then get an option which will give me the desired pop-up window with buttons, one of which is to examine media with an option to save to disk, as show in this image (from URL = https://www.maketecheasier.com/saving-multiple-images-in-firefox/ ), **but only for the contents of that frame, not for the entire page**:

[image]

Is this a newly introduced bug in the Firefox interface, or is there something that I can toggle on/off in the Firefox "special options" or "advanced" tab?  If the latter, I will need step-by-step details.

**Current environment:**

- UbuntuMATE 20.04
- Linux 5.4.0-73-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 17:39:42 UTC 2021
  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Firefox 88.0.1 (64-bit) Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing menuitem is, for better or worse, not a bug.  It was an intentional change made by Mozilla in Firefox 88.  My understanding is that are planning on bringing back that menuitem to the context menu in a future version.

In the meantime, I can recommend the "View Image Info Reborn", available on AMO here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/view-image-info-reborn/

The extension brings back some of the previous functionality and also adds new related functionality that improves on the previous behavior.  The extension was written by Jefferson Scher, who has volunteered his time helping Mozilla and the Firefox community for many years.

Here is a screenshot illustrating some of the great functionality of the extension:

[image: screenshot of View Image Info Reborn extension]
*Source: Mozilla Firefox addons repository*

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, why not just Ctrl+I 'ing it in the meantime? Or just use it from the drop-down menu>Tools-section> instead..
..And yeah, I was dissatisfied with said change as well.. And still am, as 1½ years later; we're still missing the context-menu button for the aforementioned 'Page Info'.
[Please excuse the necromancy concerning this thread, but I felt it pertinent to add more info to this page:]

Also, by now you must've already checked the about:config; so did I, and once more just now, but found no relevant variable affecting the aforementioned tool, nor accessibility to it.

If one needs the 'Page Info' accessible from the context-menu on an up-to-date Firefox, I suppose they should follow the yellow brick road, to seek the favor of a tech-wizard adept in the arcane arts of addons and browser extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The window is still available, though access to it has been moved. Mozilla has a help page explaining how to open the information page.

[Firefox Page Info window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-page-info-window)

The short of it is, there are three ways to access the Page Info window.

1. From the menubar, choose Tools | Page Info
2. From the padlock in the address bar, choose Connection secure | More information
3. From the keyboard, Control + I (Windows/Linux) or Command + I (macOS)